# Viewing Swagger API documentation

Tags: php, laravel, swagger, swagger-ui, laravel-5.7

I am attempting to generate swagger(openapi) api documentation for a laravel 5.7 app using [swagger-php](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php) and [l5-swagger](https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger)

This is my first attempt and here is how I have gone about it following the documentation

1. composer require zircote/swagger-php
2. composer require darkaonline/l5-swagger
3. Added `L5Swagger\L5SwaggerServiceProvider::class,` to config/app.php file
4. Added annotations to BookController
5. Ran the command `php artisan l5-swagger:generate`

My BookController looks like this with the annotations

```
/**
 * @OA\Info(
 *      version="1.0.0",
 *      title="Laravel Test OpenApi",
 *      description="L5 Swagger OpenApi description",
 *      @OA\Contact(
 *          email="menadio1@gmail.com"
 *      ),
 *     @OA\License(
 *         name="Apache 2.0",
 *         url="http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
 *     )
 * )
 */
/**
 *  @OA\Server(
 *      url=L5_SWAGGER_CONST_HOST,
 *      description="L5 Swagger OpenApi dynamic host server"
 *  )
 *
 *  @OA\Server(
*      url="https://projects.dev/api/v1",
 *      description="L5 Swagger OpenApi Server"
 * )
 */

class BookController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @OA\Get(
     *      path="/books",
     *      operationId="getBooksList",
     *      tags={"Books"},
     *      summary="Get list of books",
     *      description="Returns list of books",
     *      @OA\Response(
     *          response=200,
     *          description="successful operation"
     *       ),
     *       @OA\Response(response=400, description="Bad request"),
     *     )
     *
     * Returns list of books
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return BookResource::collection(Book::all());
    }
}
```

Now how can I view the api documentation? I have absolutely no idea the url to use and would appreciate some help.

Comment: What library do you currently use to generate documentation for Laravel 8.x ?

Answer (score 3):

Resolved. The correct url to load swagger UI was `http://localhost:8000/api/documentation`

I hope it saves someone else some quality development time.